# using foreach loop for multiple MySQL inserts

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using the following snippet to break up an string array, then insert them into the database.

```
//split tags into individual words
        $tag_array = explode(',', $tags);

        foreach($tag_array as $tag){
            addslashes($tag);
            echo $tag."&nbsp;";
            $addTagsQuery = "INSERT INTO `my_blog`.`tags` (`id`, `name`) VALUES 
            ('".$id."', '".$tag."');";
            $tagsResult = $db->query($addTagsQuery);
            if($tagsResult){
                echo "tag added <br />";
            }
            else {
                echo "tag was not added <br />";
            }

        }
```

My problem lies within a scenario where multiple tag (strings) are submitted. Unfortunately, only the first string in the array is inserted. Any insight as to why only the first string in the array is inserted into the MySQL database would be appreciated.

Comment: Where's that `$id` coming from?

Comment: nope, but the way its coded, you could be wide open to SQL-Injection attacks

Comment: you need to add some debugging in your code. echo as many info as possible - every variable, query results, etc. I bet you don't even have an idea, what's  $tags variable content is.

Comment: true, not much security added.  In the future, I'll add some checks to validate the entry. Right now I'm only striving for basic functionality since I know exactly what $tags variable content is for now.

Comment: another lack-of-debugging question. and bunch anything-but-on-topic answers

Answer (score 4):

$id is not being incremented in the loop. Chances are you are getting a duplicate error, but for whatever reason it is not telling you (poor error handling?).

```
$addTagsQuery = "INSERT INTO `my_blog`.`tags` (`name`) VALUES 
            ('".$tag."');";
```

If the ID is auto_incrementing, just omit and it will handle that for you.

Comment: I turned off auto_incrementing and primary key.  I want to have one blog id (i.e.: blog id = 1) that could have multiple tags.

Comment: @smafu_1: Then the column name `id` is a bit misleading as it is not an identity for the row. Perhaps it could be called blog_id instead.

Answer (score 4):

- You should use an auto-incrementing id instead of setting the id manually.
- You don't need to run multiple insert statements. You can do it in one statement:

  ```
  INSERT INTO my_blog.tags (name) VALUES ('tag1'), ('tag2')
  ```
- The function [`addslashes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) doesn't modify the string so the way you are using it will have no effect.
- You should use bind parameters instead of escaping strings.

Comment: +1 - Using combined inserts like this is much more efficient as well.

Answer (score 0):

$id is the id of the blog entry the tags are submitted for? Do you maybe have turned ID into a primary key or otherwise unique? That could cause the problem.

Comment: Correct. It is the id of the blog entry. It was the primary key and i changed it for that reason so that I could insert multiple entries with the same number.

Comment: hm. here's what I'd do then: try printing out the sql commands, and enter them to the commandline. See if you get an error function.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
$tag_array = explode(',', $tags);
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO my_blog.tags (id, name) VALUES (?,?)");
foreach($tag_array as $tag){
    if ($stmt->execute(Array($id, $tag))){
        echo "tag added <br />";
    }
    else{
        echo "tag was not added <br />";
    }
    $stmt->closeCursor();
}
```